# Euler formula - equivalent angles

Tags: complex-numbers

How does $e^{−5π i/6} = − \cos(π/6)−i\sin(π/6)$? Shouldn't the argument for the $\cos$ and $\sin$ be $5*\pi/6$?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to guess what you meant. Try to write mathematics following the easy directions in this site. Did you mean $\;e^{-5\pi i/6}\;$ ?

Comment: Apologies, I'm a newbie. Anyway thats exactly what I mean, e−5πi/6 = exp(-5*pi/6)

Comment: Read my answer, perhaps that'll clear things out.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-5\pi i/6}=\cos\frac{5\pi}6-i\sin\frac{5\pi}6=-\cos\frac\pi6-i\sin\frac\pi6$$

since, by trigonometric identities:

$$\cos x=-\cos(\pi-x)\;,\;\;\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$$

Comment: Many Thanks Joanpemo!

Comment: @Arsenal123 My pleasure.